# How to get object's class name?

Tags: php

Assuming `var_dump`'s output of my object looks like following:

```
template: object(HTMLTemplateDeliverySlip)#158 (7) {
  ["order"]=>
  object(Order)#164 (62) {
  (...)
```

how can I print the name between brackets, which is `(HTMLTemplateDeliverySlip)` ?

Comment: Look at get_class() http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
echo get_class($object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the name of the class using get_class function:

```
echo get_class($obj);
```